# Please Explain me Below lines with code?(Recursion In Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

```
define function, speller
  if there are no more letters
    print "all done"
  print the first letter
  invoke speller with the given name minus the first letter
```

If we invoked this function with “Zoe” as the argument, we would see “Z”, “o”, and “e” printed out before “all done”.

We call the function a total of 4 times!

function called with “Zoe”
function called with “oe”
function called with “e”
function called with “”

Comment: yes, this is just a definition. can you write code for this

Answer (score 1):

Recursive means the function should call itself from within the method:

```
def speller(word):
    if not word:
        print('all done')
        return

    print(word[0])
    speller(word[1::])

speller('Zoe')
```

Output:

```
>> Python 3.6.8 (default, Jun 11 2019, 01:21:42)
>> [GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
>> Z
>> o
>> e
>> all done
```

https://repl.it/repls/CoolAmusedPlots

Comment: True this is recursion but that example should be done using a loop and an iterator. Not only does the recursion take up stack but the `[1::]` slice is also taking up extra memory on each call for no good reason (at least for this type of problem).

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse feel free to edit

Comment: It answers the question. My reply was more for the OP.